# How to apply boolean condition vector to each column of the dataframe something like: Dataframe[booleanVector, : ]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let IX be some boolean vector (or may be dataframe with logical values),
 df - dataframe of the same len.

I want to get something like **df[IX,:]**,
 i.e. for each column of dataframe get those elements for which **IX = true**.

**Question:** Is there some simple way to do it ?

---

**I tried** : The ways I tried 1) df[IX] 2) df.loc[IX,:] does not seem to work

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'Col' : 1. , 'Col2' : 1.1 }, index= ['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={ 'ColDF2' : 2.  }, index= ['C', 'D'])
IX = df2>0
IX.index = df.index
print(df)
print(df2)
print(IX)
print(df[IX] )
```

Output:

```
   Col  Col2
A  1.0   1.1
B  1.0   1.1
   ColDF2
C     2.0
D     2.0
  ColDF2
A   True
B   True
   Col  Col2
A  NaN   NaN
B  NaN   NaN
```

I want to get:

```
   Col  Col2
A  1.0   1.1
B  1.0   1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need select column for condition and then use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by `boolean numpy array` created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
IX = df2['ColDF2']>0

print(df[IX.values])
   Col  Col2
A  1.0   1.1
B  1.0   1.1

print(IX.values)
[ True  True]
```

Or create same index values in mask like in your answer:

```
IX = df2['ColDF2'] > 0
IX.index = df.index
print(df[IX])
   Col  Col2
A  1.0   1.1
B  1.0   1.1

print(IX)
A    True
B    True
Name: ColDF2, dtype: bool
```

If `df2` has only one column:

```
IX = df2>0
print (IX)
   ColDF2
C    True
D    True

print(df[IX.values])
   Col  Col2
A  1.0   1.1
B  1.0   1.1

print (IX.values)
[[ True]
 [ True]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it works! I should use IX.values and
 that solves the problems ...